# Detect ongoing write operation on a networkstream

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, tcp, server

Imagine a server application is connected via TCP to some client device. The user of the server decides to send some message to the client device with NetworkStream.BeginWrite, but due to a slow connection or some other unknown factor, the server calls BeginWrite, but BeginWrite has not yet finished its write and performed its callback. In the meantime, the user decides to disconnect the client device in the main thread, causing an ObjectDisposedException to be immediately thrown in the callback due to the underlying connection no longer being available.

Here's a pseudo example of what I mean:

```
/// bad pseudo of possible code happening in main server thread    
while(!quit){
    if( command has been inputted) {
          switch (command) {
               case send:
                    string m = getAStringFromGUI();
                    Send(m);
               break;
               case disconnect:
                    ClientDevice.Close();
               break;
          }
    } 
}

private void Send(string msg){
    NetworkStream stream;

    byte[ ] packetBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    stream = clientDevice.GetStream();
    stream.BeginWrite(packetBuffer, 0, packetBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(StreamWriteCompleteCallback), stream);
}
private void StreamWriteCompleteCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    try {
        NetworkStream stream = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
        stream.EndWrite(ar);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
        // client device was disconnected by the server before write completed
    }
}
```

If a disconnect command is entered fast enough after the send command, the exception will be thrown. Obviously in this simple example, you could block until the write is complete, but what if you wanted to have the writes to occur asynchronously but still prevent disconnect commands from executing until any write commands have completed (or timed out)? I believe you could keep track of all the BeginWrite calls with waithandles, and utilize those to ensure writes complete before disconnecting, but that seems like a lot of work. Is there any way to know whether any thread is attempting to write to a given network stream?

Answer (score 0):

You need to track manually the request, but it's more easy than you think, a simple concurrent dictionary would be enough for this:

```
//This class will store ongoing requests and also will be used as the async parameter
public class ExecutingRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public NetworkStream Stream { get; set; }
}

//Somewhere in your server class
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ExecutingRequest> pendingRequests = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ExecutingRequest>();

private void Send(string msg)
{
    NetworkStream stream;

    byte[ ] packetBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    stream = clientDevice.GetStream();
    var request = new ExecutingRequest{ Stream = stream, Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
    pendingRequests.AddOrUpdate(request.Id, request, (a,b) => request);
    stream.BeginWrite(packetBuffer, 0, packetBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(StreamWriteCompleteCallback), request);
}

private void StreamWriteCompleteCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
    try {
        ExecutingRequest req = (ExecutingRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        pendingRequests.TryRemove(req.Id, out ExecutingRequest dummy);
        req.stream.EndWrite(ar);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException) 
    {
        // client device was disconnected by the server before write completed
    }
}
```

Then, you can check if there is any request running by checking the length of the dictionary.

Comment: This is not sufficient, because it doesn't solve the race condition of one thread, having checked the dictionary, being about to call `.Dispose()`, while another is about to call `.BeginWrite()`. If you want to exclude the possibility that any `.BeginWrite()` is interrupted by a `.Dispose()`, there must be mutual exclusion. Also, there is technically no need to track individual requests, you can simply track the count of outstanding requests.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Just to clarify - if I wanted to close a specific connection, but first wait for its request to finish, wouldn't I need to track all individual requests? Because otherwise, how would you know that the currently outstanding requests have anything to do with the connection you're trying to close

Comment: @Cobalt: I mean "count of outstanding requests per stream". I'd personally abstract this away behind a class that wraps the client and any requests made on that connection, but even if you used a central collection as here (which I wouldn't, because you're setting up a locking hotspot), it's sufficient to increase/decrease the pending count per stream. Tracking the whole request may have some value for diagnostic purposes, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Ah, I see what you're saying. As for the race condition, would it work to simply wrap each connection with a mutex and enclose each attempt to write or close the connection with something like `Mutex.WaitOne()` and `Mutex.ReleaseMutex()`? Or am I thinking about this wrong

Comment: @Cobalt: a `Monitor` is simpler than a full mutex. Close: `lock (client) { while (pendingRequestCount != 0) Monitor.Wait(client); client.Close(); }` Send: `lock (client) { ++pendingRequestCount; } ; send(...);`. Completion callback: `lock(client) { --pendingRequestCount; if (pendingRequestCount == 0) Monitor.PulseAll(client); }`. Careful with aborted requests though, the count must be correct or you're going to have some nasty bugs. Code using async/await will need something like Stephen Cleary's `AsyncMonitor`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I very well be missing something here (coffee hasn't kicked in), so be kind, but if each client had a mutex to ensure threads had exclusive access to the stream, would you even need to track pending requests? Mutex would ensure only one write/disconnect per connection at a time

Comment: @Cobalt: Sure. That's assuming you only want a single pending write request on the stream. This is not unreasonable, but it wasn't explicitly stated anywhere in the question. It is not an error to have multiple outstanding write requests on a `NetworkStream` (but the order they complete in is not defined).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I can see how for a large scale server, the constraint of one write request at a time would be undesirable, but I believe this will be an acceptable and simple solution for me. Thanks!